# I'm looking for a photo management software that works on Android & Windows

Tags: windows, android, file-management, photography

I have tried Plex & Google Photos but neither meets all my requirements:

- I want to be able to put photos in multiple albums at once
- Face recognition & sorting is a plus point, but I want to be able to add pictures manually too, which makes Google Photos feature useless for me.
- I want to be able to access my photos offline, at least from PC, but ideally also from my android phone.
- A big plus would also be the ability to go through the photos in windows explorer, but it's not a must-have.

Anyways, Plex has failed me on the Offline-thing, and it's not an option for me to always leave my PC running. Google photos also doesn't have an offline option, and the really good face recognition is so wasted because I can't add photos to it manually :(

I hope someone can help me and either suggest fixes for these apps, or suggest an app that works offline.

Answer (score 0):

i use

- [Digikam](http://digikam.org/) on pc
- [A Photo Manager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki) on Android where i am the author of
- and [syncthing](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/) to transfer photos between android and pc as described in [pc android meta sync](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/sync)

Currently i am working on ["virtual albums"](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/issues/115) and i am looking for somebody to help me to [integrate into digikam](http://digikam.1695700.n4.nabble.com/Metadata-sync-with-android-app-where-to-start-td4696047.html)

Comment: I test Digikam, and it was painfully slow it took 4 days to scan my library.  Facing matching was a joke, 99% of the matches were so far often it might as well as have been guessing.  Dozens if not 100's of faces that were NOT even close.